# MVC4 Bundling slow when using Scripts.Render

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle, bundling-and-minification

My asp.net MVC4 web project is running very slowly when serving a simple page that renders bundled scripts. However, when I use a 'hardcoded' script tag on the page with the source attribute of the virtual bundle path then performance is much better:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts")                            ~ 4 seconds
```

vs

```
<script src='@Scripts.Url("~/bundles/scripts")'></script>       < 1 second
```

My `BundleConfig.cs` has no special configuration, this is exactly as it appears:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js",
    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js",
    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.min.js",
    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-modal.js",
    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-dropdown.js",
    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-tooltip.js",
    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-typeahead.js",
    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-transition.js",
    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-popover.js"));
```

My `web.config` is even configured to optimize in Debug but I have tried running in Release mode and still get the same result:

```
<compilation optimizeCompilations="true" debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
```

**Any ideas why `Scripts.Render` is so slow?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was with the outdated package I had installed. A simple `Update-Package` in package manager console and I went from

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization"
    version="1.0.0-beta2" targetFramework="net40" />
```

to

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization"
    version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
```

Now `Scripts.Render()` is peforming much better :-)

Comment: On 1.1.0 and seeing some insanely large load times for script bundles (10 .js files)... Consistently getting 7-9 seconds... anyone else?

Comment: I have this issue as well. Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Same here, this issue is driving me crazy, any solution?

Comment: I bundled several custom scripts and all of a sudden sites are loading between 30-90 seconds...

Comment: I have a new package, but it's still slow.  Any suggestion?
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />

Comment: I have the exact same problem with the version 1.1.3 of Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization package